# insert from one table into another table sql using join or update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I currently have two tables as seen in the pictures below.

The first table is called `bottles`:

[image]

And the second table is called `cases`:

[image]

I am trying to insert into the bottles table where case_id = 0 the two values seen in the cases table (ie case_id=100). They are two seperate tables and I am trying to join them.

Please let me know if I need to use insert, join, or update. I would manually do it however these data points are coming live from a PLC and there will be many more than just the two seen below.

Comment: So you want to replace all 0 values in column bottles.case_id with value 100? If so, just run `UPDATE bottles SET case_id = 100 WHERE case_id = 0`. Otherwise please clarify how the values in table bottle and cases are linked.

Comment: Do you want to replace the case_id to be 100 or do you want to add two new rows? The previous one is update, the second one is to insert.

Comment: I want to be able to replace 0 values with values corresponding to another table so sometimes the 0 should be 100. sometimes it should be 101. I want to replace every 4 zero values with a value over 100 increment up by 1.

Comment: can you please update questioning with example test data.

Comment: how are you inserting the data into the first table? seems like you're forgetting to insert the foreign key